# How to update all records as quickly as possible?

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to update all the records with the same value. And I don't want to do it with iteration over objects since that takes about 2 seconds for over 2000 objects. Basically I have all users locally and I receive the users id's from the server. I now want to set property 'requested' to false except for the users return from the server-

How it is done now (which is totally wrong!):

Iterating thru all users (about 2000 of them) and correcting their requested value.

```
NSFetchRequest * allUsers = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[allUsers setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:allUsers error:&error];

NSArray *userIDs = [JSON objectForKey:@"users_ids"];
for (User *user in users) {
    if ([userIDs containsObject:user.userID]) {
        user.requested = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    } else {
        user.requested = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
    user.requested = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
}
[context save:nil];
```

My idea how to do it:

Set requested=false for every object with a sql-like one statement. Going thru id's returned by the server (20 on average) and setting requested=true for those.

```
// UPDATE users SET requested = false WHERE 1=1

NSArray *userIDs = [JSON objectForKey:@"users_ids"];
for (int i = 0; i < [userIDs count]; i++) {
    User *user = [User userWithServerID:[userIDs[i] integerValue] usingManagedObjectContext:context];
    user.requested = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}
[context save:nil];
```

So how could I update all the records with one "query" ? Or does anyone have any better idea how to implement this (more performance efficient way of doing the iteration perhaps) ?

Putting this in the background thread is a solution (perhaps), but I would still like to optimise it first before putting it in the background thread.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You would still have to fetch all the objects but you can do it all in one line.

```
[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setYourValue:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Or just cycle the array

```
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:allRequest error:&error];
[objects setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"user_ids"];
//now save your changes back.
[context save:&error];
```